# populate select boxes from json string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of select boxes with incremental numbers to identify then e.g.

```
<select id="my-select-0">
  <option value="1">first option</option>
  <option value="2">first option</option>
< option value="3">first option</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select-1">
  <option value="1">first option</option>
  <option value="2">first option</option>
  <option value="3">first option</option>
</select>
<select id="my-select-2">
  <option value="1">first option</option>
  <option value="2">first option</option>
  <option value="3">first option</option>
</select>
```

I have a json string which I want to use to pre populate these selects e.g.

```
json = "[{'my-select': 1}, 
         {'my-select': 3}]";
```

in the example above `my-select-0` would be set to 1 and `my-select-1` is set to 3.

How would I go about doing this in JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Do you control this format?  Currently it's not valid JSON, so you won't be able to use any of the built-in functions to parse it.  Is it fetched via AJAX, or just rendered directly in the page?

Comment: I control the JSON string. I'm new to JSON so can you tell me what the correct format should be? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're after, but if you change the JSON to be [valid](http://www.jsonlint.com/) (double quotes) you can do it using [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and looping through, like this:

```
var json = '[{"my-select": 1}, {"my-select": 3}]';​​​​​​​​​

var selects = $("[id^=my-select]"); //a class maybe? not sure of your options
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function(i, v) {
    selects.eq(i).val(v['my-select']);
});
​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/32xqm/)

---

**Update:** Since you control how this is rendered in the page just remove the initial quotes it's wrapped in, like this:

```
var json = [{'my-select': 1}, {'my-select': 3}];
var selects = $("[id^=my-select]");
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
    selects.eq(i).val(v['my-select']);
});
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/32xqm/1/), JSON is exactly what it's name says, *object notation*...so just use it that way, don't make it a string, just output/declare it directly as a javascript object...in this case it's an array you can loop through, and it's of course faster without all that extra work.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I want.  However I am using jquery 1.3.0 which doesn't have the parseJSON function.  Is your solution possible using 1.3.0?  Thanks

Comment: @John - How are you getting the JSON string? is it rendered into the page, or fetched via AJAX?

Comment: rendered into the page just as you have it above i.e. json = ???
The string itself is dynamically created using server side scripting.

Comment: @John - I updated the answer given the new info, the approach is much simpler and will work in jQuery 1.3.0 as well, let me know if you have any trouble :)